# Polygon not is not filling in android mapview

Tags: android, google-maps, canvas, fill, polygons

I am trying to draw a filled polygon on a map view in my app. No matter what I have tried it  will not draw filled in. I can get the strokes to show up but I can not get it to fill. Below is the draw method of my polygon class. It overrides overlays.

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow);

            Paint mPaint = new Paint();

            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);

            Paint mPaintFill = new Paint();

            mPaintFill.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mPaintFill.setColor(Color.GREEN);

            Path path = new Path();

            GeoPoint start = route.get(0);
            for (int i = 1; i < route.size(); ++i) {
                    Point p1 = new Point();
                    Point p2 = new Point();

                    Projection projection = mapv.getProjection();
                    projection.toPixels(start, p1);
                    projection.toPixels(route.get(i), p2);

                    path.moveTo(p2.x, p2.y);
                    path.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y);

                    start = route.get(i);
            }              


            canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(path, mPaintFill);
            //canvas.clipPath(path, Op.DIFFERENCE); 
    }
```

The above code for me will draw the lines correctly but it doesn't get filled in. Removing canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint); and just leaving the fill one results in nothing showing on the map. I have even tried setting Paint.Style.STROKE to Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE. I am at a complete loss and at this point am thinking it is something simple I am over looking.

Comment: it's not your answer but it's a suggestion. This map API is being deprecated and I've used already the new one and it's 100% simpler to implement and it will have a long support. Maybe you should just ditch this and implement the API V2